# How to use similar_text() in a difficult context

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, similarity

I'm working on a PHP code that plays music tracks by fetching sources from some audio/video APIs.

I need to compare my data (*track artist* + *track title*) with the sources titles to see if the source is relevant; because your search on some APIs (eg. Youtube) will always return you some results, no matter it does not match your search... Youtube try to make you *watch* something.

**My idea was**

1. To search for the *track artist* in the *source title* : if the *track artist* is missing from the *source title*, source should be ignored.
2. To calculate the similarity between the track title and the source title using [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php).  Under a certain value, source would be ignored.
3. To get more precision, I would remove the *track artist* from the *source title* before using similar_text().
4. I would also have standardized both inputs using the function [sanitize_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) (Wordpress) to make the comparisons easier.

> Sigur Rós -> sigur-ros

**The problem is** that the track data (*track artist* + *track title*) is often written differently than in the *source title*.

> Bob Marley and the Wailers != Bob Marley & Wailers

**I feel I would rather need to**

1. Split the *source title* to get the *(source) track artist* and *(source) track title*.
2. Use similar_text() on *track artist* and *(source) track artist* - ignore source if under a certain value.
3. Use similar_text() on *track title* and *(source) track title* - ignore source if under a certain value.

But I can't extract the *(source) track artist* and *(source) track title* since I can't rely on an exact name, so this cannot work.

How would you handle this ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Usually it's best to use something designed for this purpose - like [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/).

Comment: @Scopey : could you explain a little more ?